# useState() within useEffect() in a functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried to change a class based component into a functional component and run into troubles when I tried to read state properties inside a handler function attached with `useEffect()`

Inside the class based component I'll attach the handler method inside `componentDidMount` and this handler has access to the state.

The rendered output does show the correct values in both types of components!

But when I need the current value of the state property inside my handler to calculate the new state values I run into troubles reading the state properties
inside functional components.

I created following example to demonstrate the problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-wozniak-l6w2c (open console and scroll)

If you click on the components both work fine:

- console outputs the current value of the state property `counter`
- incremenet the state property `counter`

If you scroll only the class based component works:

- console outputs the current value of the state property `position`
- update the state property `position`

But the console output from the functional components only returns me
the initial state property value.

**class based component**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class CCTest extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { position: 0, counter: 0 };
    this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleScroll(e) {
    console.log(
      "class.handleScroll()",
      this.state.position
    );
    this.setState({ position: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().top });
  }

  handleClick() {
    console.log("[class.handleClick]", this.state.counter);
    this.setState(prevState => ({ counter: prevState.counter + 1 }));
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "orange",
          padding: "20px",
          cursor: "pointer"
        }}
        onClick={this.handleClick}
      >
        <strong>class</strong>
        <p>
          position: {this.state.position}, counter: {this.state.counter}
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**functional component**

```
import React from "react";

export default prop => {
  const [position, setPosition] = React.useState(0);
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  const handleScroll = () => {
    console.log(
      "function.handleScroll()",
      position
    );
    setPosition(document.body.getBoundingClientRect().top);
  };

  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log("[function.handleClick]", counter);
    setCounter(counter + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div
      style={{ backgroundColor: "green", padding: "20px", cursor: "pointer" }}
      onClick={handleClick}
    >
      <strong>function</strong>
      <p>
        position: {position}, counter: {counter}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Every little hint helps <3

Comment: What is the question exactly ?

Comment: How to gain access to the state property `position` from the `handleScroll` function inside the **functional component**

Comment: my console output doesnt match the output inside the the components (function.handleScroll() 0) all over the place - I am using the newest chrome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every time your component renders, a new handleScroll function is created, which has access through the component closure to the current state. But this closure doesn't get updated on every render; instead, a new handleScroll function is created, which sees the new values.

The problem is that when you do:

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
```

You're binding the *current* version of the function to the event, and it will always read the values at that time, instead of new ones. Normally, useEffect would be run again and a new instance of the function would be used, but you're preventing it with the empty array as the second parameter.

There is a linter warning just for these cases, but you have disabled it:

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line
```

If you remove this empty array, you can remove the linter disabling rule, and it will work properly.

**Other options**

When having the function change every time is not an option (for example, when using non-react libraries, or for performance reasons), there are other alternatives:

- You can use a [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) instead of state. Refs get mutated instead of a new one being created on every render. This allows previous versions of the function to read the current value, and modify it, even if you don't update the function.
- You can use [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer). The dispatch function never changes, so if your useEffect depends on it, it won't be re-run. The reducer can access both the previous value and the action, so it can calc the new state even if it depends on the previous one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so functional components have to rebind the handler everytime the components render while class based components only need to bind the handler once? Any way to achieve the same result without rebinding the handler every render?

Comment: Yes, I just added another option to the answer. Just be careful because using refs for this makes your code harder to understand, and should only be done when actually needed.

Comment: Thank you sir, so you would suggest Refs in this case for the sake of performance?

Comment: A short example isn't enough to be sure of what would be the best option: it depends on the specific of what you're trying to do. But my first option here would probably be a completely different one: useReducer. You can just dispatch a scroll action (and the dispatch function doesn't change), and the reducer updates the value. I can add this to my answer if you'd like.

Comment: Would be super lovely! Big thanks for your extended help!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the help of @Anxo I ended up ditching `useState` and utilize `useRecuder` instead.

This is my **functional component** for the specific example in the initial question:

```
import React from 'react';

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'UPDATE_POSITION':
      return {
        ...state,
        position: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().top
      };
    case 'INCREMENT_COUNTER':
      return {
        ...state,
        counter: state.counter + 1
      };
    default:
      throw new Error('chalupa batman');
  }
};

const initialState = {
  position: 0,
  counter: 0
};

const FCTest = props => {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
      dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_POSITION' });
    });
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener(
        'scroll',
        dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_POSITION' })
      );
    };
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      style={{ backgroundColor: 'green', padding: '20px', cursor: 'pointer' }}
      onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT_COUNTER' })}
    >
      <strong>function</strong>
      <p>
        position: {state.position}, counter: {state.counter}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FCTest;
```